# SQL Server MODEL Clause

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Does SQL Server have something similar to Oracle's MODEL clause? http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/model_clause/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply... no. It does not. Not saying that it's not possible to write query producing the same output using SQL Server instruments. Even complex MODEL clauses can be usually rewritten using common table expressions and analytic functions but resulting query is much more complex both for a human to read, understand and maintain and for database to execute.

Comment: Yea I figured. I'm trying to avoid doing a quirky table update

Comment: You can try to post the actual query as a new question for people to try out rewriting it to SQL Server dialect.

Comment: Thanks. I've posted a better question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33200664/quirky-update-reliability-alternatives